# Find the duration of an OGG music file in java

Tags: java, ogg

I wrote the following code to determine the duration of an OGG (Vorbis) file.

```
public static long calculateDuration(final File file) throws IOException {
    long fileSize = (Files.size(file.toPath())); // Bytes
    byte[] nominalBitrateBytes = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    try (RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            randomAccessFile.seek(48L + i);
            nominalBitrateBytes[i] = randomAccessFile.readByte();
        }
    }
    long nominalBitrate = ByteBuffer.wrap(nominalBitrateBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong();
    return fileSize / (nominalBitrate / 8);
}
```

With this I'm reading the filesize with java.nio library and the nominal bitrate that I found out it's stored in a 64bit value starting at the 48th byte in the music file.

The problem is sometimes that the value comes out wrong and sometimes is actually accurate. For example I took a music file with a duration of 3.55min. The code outputs 227 seconds, which is near 235 of the track. As a second attempt I processed a 2.03min track, and the software's guess was 102 seconds, that is too far low (should be 123). By trying to do this calculations by hand it turns out the same values as the software (taking the filesize  with explorer.exe and the bitrate with HxD)

Comment: So if I get you correctly, you are calculating the duration by dividing the file size by the bitrate? But you are already reading metadata from the same file. So why would you expect an accurate answer?

Comment: Also tried excluding the metadata in the calculation (less than a kB), ad as you can imagine the result doesn't change. I'm not expecting any accurate answer, but a 20 seconds error is too much.

Comment: `bitrate stored in a 64bit value starting at the 48th byte` just no, ogg is container format, it can contain multiple streams encoded by different codes, also different parts of stream can have different bitrates, so there is no way current approach work, you need to properly parse it

Comment: Does this solution help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794204/how-to-determine-length-of-ogg-file Note that it has the same caveats about encoding and multiple streams that Ilya Bursov mentioned

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bogg%5D+length may also help. If these do not answer your question, make an edit to your question explaining any test cases or other cirucmstances. If you can edit and add a link to a few test files of known lengths that would help too

Comment: Using the code in the thread i get this number 33738.5, and the track's duration should be 123 seconds

Comment: Okay it seems to work. I changed the first two variables' type from int to long

Comment: Duration covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794204/how-to-determine-length-of-ogg-file#:~:text=The%20quickest%20way%20to%20do,per%20channel%20in%20the%20file).
)